# rbenv rehash gives me Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, bundler, rbenv

After upgrading to Rails 4.0.4 and Ruby 2.1.1, i have permission problems with rbenv rehash. I tried bundler install to 1.5.3. Ok. But still no. bashrc (Ubuntu 13.04) is fine, that is, as before. ruby -v shows the proper versions of global and local Ruby, as does rails -v. Only 'rehash' seems to be the problem.

```
.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:187:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen
```

Comment: A fresh re-install of rbenv was my solution, which in my case was preferable, anyway. Yet, if anyone knows of a quick and dirty solution to the above error, it may come in handy someday...when time is of the essence )

Answer (score 0):

Try running the server as a root.

> sudo -s
>
> rails s

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner of the dependency files:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /.rvm/
```

And then change owner of the project file:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /var/www/PROJECTFILE
```